# Rails generate audited:install error , not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I m using **Rails 4** & `gem 'audited', '~> 4.2'`
I tried both `rails generate audited:install` and `audited install` commands after installing Audited gem, but I'm not getting *audit.rb* file,
instead I'm getting a `Could not find generator 'audited:install'` error.

Is there any other command? Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you did to install whatever you've got installed, what commands you run or actions you take, and the *specific* results, including any error message or other output.

Comment: could you post your full error message stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Lahiru ,

In Gemfile:(add one more gem with audited)

```
gem "audited", "~> 4.0"

gem 'audited-activerecord', '~> 4.2'
```

$ bundle install

$ rails generate audited:install

Its working for me.